# Redirecting example.com and keeping example.com/login

Tags: web-services, dns, subdomain

This might be obvious, but I want to redirect anybody that arrives to `example.com` to `site.example.com`, but I want to keep `example.com/login intact`.

Can I accomplish this and what will be the best way?

Comment: It is not a DNS-related task.
Which web service are you using? i.e. Apache, Nginx, IIS etc.

Comment: I'm using Apache.